# The release pipeline cannot be saved because the stage 'Prod' references a service connection that cannot be found

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-task

In AzureDevOps when saving a Release Pipeline I get the error:

**VS402913: The release pipeline cannot be saved because the stage 'Prod' references a service connection that cannot be found, or that you do not have permission to access.**

> VS402913: The release pipeline cannot be saved because the stage 'Prod' references a service connection that cannot be found, or that you do not have permission to access. Details: 'Task 'Load Azure Key Vault' is using service connection '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',Task 'Delete stage slot' is using service connection '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',Task 'Create App Service Slot' is using service connection '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',Task 'Stop all continuous webjobs' is using service connection '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',Task 'Deploy Arfifacts' is using service connection '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',Task 'Migrate Database' is using service connection '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',Task 'Swap Slots' is using service connection '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',Task 'Start all continuous webjobs' is using service connection '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',Task 'Cleanup Stage Slot' is using service connection '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',Task 'Deploy APIM' is using service connection '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000''

For all the variables it reports they need access to the the Service Connections:
[image]

How can I save the Pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to set the Variables either Pipeline variables or Variable groups

[image]

Comment: This seems like an obvious "fix". But when you got the error, were there any variables linked to your release pipeline for the specified stage (prod)?

Comment: No, the error message was so vague it had no link to the variables, it was misleading saying **xyz is using service connection**. I compared this pipeline to a working one and that's how I found out this was the difference.